# Reading data across clusters in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge table which I am loading from RedShift into a csv file on S3 using a Databricks(DBx) notebookA. This notebook is running on clusterA.
I have another notebookB, which is reading the data from csv files in S3 into a dataframe. This notebookB is running on clusterB.
Now, I want to access this dataframe in third notebookC, which is on clusterC.
How can I do this?
registerTempTable is session specific.
createGlobalTempView can be accessed across notebooks but not across notebooks on different clusters.

Comment: I think that is not possible. As long as you have independent clusters you have to transfer your code and your data to one cluster.

Comment: Thanks for responding mate..Any thoughts about any alternatives?

Comment: Why don't you just read all the data from clusterC? According to your description all the data is stored on S3.